# Getting the error message from v8::Script::Compile()

Tags: c++, v8

I'm calling `Script::Compile()` and it returns me an empty handle as result. I've traced into this method and finally found that

```
 i::Handle<i::SharedFunctionInfo> result = i::Compiler::Compile(str, ....
```

is returning the empty handle. That means compilation error.

But does anyone know is there a way to get error message from compuler in this case to get know where error has occured?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the `ReportException` function in the [`Shell` example](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/branch-heads/5.8/samples/shell.cc#374).  You need to use a `v8::TryCatch` to capture the exception and report on the error.